# Protecting Wordpress Multisite from rogue programs

Tags: php, wordpress

If I have 100 sites on a wordpress multisite installation and I give admin access to multiple developers, how can I protect the system from choking if one of them writes an infinite for loop?

Comment: You may want to try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This is technically a server configuration question and therefore a candidate for ServerFault.com

You *should* be insulated against infinite loops by setting a smart upper limit on PHP's [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) (30 seconds by default), preventing users from accessing PHP's CLI, and otherwise keeping on top of server administration.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be don't give them access to the production server, just to a dev/staging version.